# Efficient way to build collections from other collections

Tags: scala

In Scala, as in many other languages, it is possible to build collections using the elements contained in other collections.

For example, it is possible to heapify a list:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue
val l = List(1,2,3,4)
```

With:

```
val pq = PriorityQueue(l:_*)
```

or:

```
val pq = PriorityQueue[Int]() ++ l
```

These are, from my point of view, two quite different approaches:

1. Use a variadic constructor and `collection:_*` which, at the end of the day, dumps the collection in an intermediate array.
2. Build an empty target collection and use the `++` method to add all the source collection elements.

From an aesthetic point of view I do prefer the first option but I am worried about `collection:_*`. I understand form "Programming In Scala" that variadic functions are translated into functions receiving an array.

Is it, in general, the second option a better solution in terms of efficiency?

Comment: Not an answer, but `l.to[PriorityQueue]` is also nice.

Comment: @TravisBrown It is even more beautiful than `riorityQueue(l:_*)` without the performance drawback. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one might be faster in some cases, but apparently when the original collection is a Seq (such as your List), Scala tries to avoid the array creation; see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/5579.html#comment-23012).

But, realistically, it probably will not ever make a difference anyway unless you are dealing with huge collections in tight loops.  These kinds of things aren't worth worrying about, so do whichever one you like; you can spare the milliseconds.

Comment: The link you provided does definitively shed light upon the topic. It is a pitty the book doesn't extend a little bit more in the description of variadic functions.